# excel2latex table: output out of page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, margins

I generated the following code for a table using `excel2latex` add-in. However in the PDF output the table is ugly and morely cut halfway and moves to the right.
Please suggest a solution.

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet4'
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Question 5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ATT} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ATNT} & ATE \\
\midrule
      &       &       &  \\
(a) True treatment parameters & 0.471 & 0.315 & 0.365866 \\
      &       &       &  \\
(b) Kernel matching estimate & 0.546 & 0.394 & 0.443377 \\
(Variability of estimation of pscores not taken into account) &       &       &  \\
      &       &       &  \\
(c) Nearest-neighbour matching estimates & 0.448 & 0.375 & 0.398856 \\
      &       &       &  \\
(d) Treatment estimates using OLS & 0.489096 & 0.489096 & 0.489096 \\
Homogenous returns on trimmed data and specification of pscores as in Q 1 (b) &       &       &  \\
      &       &       &  \\
(e) Treatment estimates using Linear Regression & 0.587089 & 0.378109 & 0.44625 \\
      &       &       &  \\
(f) Treatment estimates using Re-weighting & 0.556587 & 0.417025 & 0.462531 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make this table fit within your page margins is to use [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). That requires you to use a `tabularx` environment (instead of `tabular`) and specify a width of the table (`\linewidth` would stretch the entire text block width).

Here's your table, wrapped in a minimal working example (uncomment the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) to see the text block boundaries):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet4'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}Xrrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Question 5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ATT} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ATNT} & ATE \\
    \midrule
      &       &       &  \\
      (a) True treatment parameters & 0.471 & 0.315 & 0.365866 \\
      &       &       &  \\
      (b) Kernel matching estimate & 0.546 & 0.394 & 0.443377 \\
      (Variability of estimation of pscores not taken into account) &       &       &  \\
      &       &       &  \\
      (c) Nearest-neighbour matching estimates & 0.448 & 0.375 & 0.398856 \\
      &       &       &  \\
      (d) Treatment estimates using OLS & 0.489096 & 0.489096 & 0.489096 \\
      Homogenous returns on trimmed data and specification of pscores as in Q 1 (b) &       &       &  \\
      &       &       &  \\
      (e) Treatment estimates using Linear Regression & 0.587089 & 0.378109 & 0.44625 \\
      &       &       &  \\
      (f) Treatment estimates using Re-weighting & 0.556587 & 0.417025 & 0.462531 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

`tabularx` provides an `X` column type that fills the remainder of the text block as is needed to fill to the width specified in the second argument to `tabularx`. The [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) notation allows you to insert stuff before each `X`-column 
entry: `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}` allows for flush right/ragged left alignment, while `\arraybackslash` restores the traditional use of `\\` for a `tabular` new line.

If you're not interested in `tabularx`, you could also just use

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.5\linewidth}rrr}
%...
\end{tabular}%
```

Here a `p{<len>}` column creates a `p`aragraph-style column of width `<len>`, thereby forcing entries to wrap if necessary. This allows you to shrink the width of the table according to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

The first cell of each row is always the same size. You have very long text in this first cell, at least in some rows. One possible solution would be to make these rows multicolums, see example below. Anyway, if you want a nicer table, you will have to re-arrange something.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Question 5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ATT} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ATNT} & ATE    \\
\midrule
   &       &       &  \\
(a) True treatment parameters & 0.471 & 0.315 & 0.365866 \\
   &       &       &  \\
(b) Kernel matching estimate & 0.546 & 0.394 & 0.443377 \\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{(Variability of estimation of pscores not taken into account)}  \\
   &       &       &  \\
(c) Nearest-neighbour matching estimates & 0.448 & 0.375 & 0.398856 \\
   &       &       &  \\
(d) Treatment estimates using OLS & 0.489096 & 0.489096 & 0.489096 \\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Homogenous returns on trimmed data and specification of pscores as in    Q 1 (b)} \\
   &       &       &  \\
(e) Treatment estimates using Linear Regression & 0.587089 & 0.378109 & 0.44625 \\
   &       &       &  \\
(f) Treatment estimates using Re-weighting & 0.556587 & 0.417025 & 0.462531 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```